# How to get CDI produced entitymanager in non EJB @Dependent subclass, throwing NPE?

Tags: jpa, ejb, openjpa, websphere-8, jta

The persistence API uses JTA managed transactions which is configured in `persistence.xml`.

**EntitymanagerProducer.java**

```
@PersistenceContext( unitName = "PRO" )
EntityManager proEm;

@pro
@Produces
public EntityManager createProEntityManager () {
    return this.proEm;
}
```

The above produced `EntityManager` could be injected into any `@Stateless` bean with qualifier `@Pro` as below,

```
@Stateless
@Local( OutRepositoryBeanLocal.class )
@Remote( OutRepositoryRemote.class )
@LocalBean
@TransactionAttribute( TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY )
public class OutRepositoryBean implements OutRepositoryBeanLocal, OutRepositoryRemote {

    @Inject
    @Pro
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    OutRepository      outRepository;

    /**
     * 
     */
    @PostConstruct
    private void init () {
        this.outRepository.setEntityManager( this.entityManager );
    }
```

The above piece of code works seemlessly with no error. But while delegating the job to `@Dependent` subclasses problem arises,

**OutRepository.java**

```
@Dependent
public class OutRepository extends BaseService< Out, Long > {


public OutRepository() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
protected Class< Out > t () {
    return Out.class;
}
public List< Out > getOuts ( Long proId, String Out) { 
    CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder(); <= NPE
    CriteriaQuery< Out > criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery( t() );
    Root< Out > endPointConfig = criteriaQuery.from( t() );
    criteriaQuery.select( endPoint ); 
    TypedQuery< Out > query = this.entityManager.createQuery( criteriaQuery );
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Whereas the `BaseService.java` is an `abstract` class containing generic crud methods.

**BaseService.java**

```
@Dependent
public abstract class BaseService< T, I extends Serializable > implements BaseEntity< T, I > {


    protected abstract Class< T > t ();

    @PostConstruct
    protected abstract void init ();

    public PersistenceUnitUtil persistenceUnitUtil;
    public EntityManager       entityManager;


    @TransactionAttribute( TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY )
    @Override
    public T save ( T t ) {
        this.entityManager.persist( t ); 
        return t;
    }
```

While `outRepsitory.save()` is called there is no problem in transaction everything works great. Yet while `outRepository.getOuts(Long proId,String Out)`, Following exception occurs

```
[2/7/18 18:19:36:187 IST] 0000003d BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "getOuts" on bean "BeanId(pro-ear#pro-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#OutRepositoryBean, null)". Exception data: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.populate(MetamodelImpl.java:321)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.instantiate(MetamodelImpl.java:255)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.find(MetamodelImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.<init>(MetamodelImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getMetamodel(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:346)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerImpl.java:1649)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerImpl.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAExEmInvocation.getCriteriaBuilder(JPAExEmInvocation.java:394)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder(JPAEntityManager.java:494)
    at com.org.uck.pro.db.out.control.OutRepository.getOuts(OutRepository.java:68)
    at com.org.uck.pro.db.out.control.OutRepositoryBean.getOuts(OutRepositoryBean.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:6207)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:568)
    at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.interceptor.OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.callInterceptorsAndDecorators(OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.java:528)
    at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.common.interceptor.OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.callToOwbInterceptors(OpenWebBeansEjbInterceptor.java:200)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
    at org.apache.webbeans.ejb.WSEJBInterceptor.callToOwbInterceptors(WSEJBInterceptor.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:6098)
    at com.org.uck.pro.db.out.boundary.EJSLocal1SLOutRepositoryBean_03076fb6.getOuts(EJSLocal1SLOutRepositoryBean_03076fb6.java)
    at com.org.uck.pro.ejb.outs.control.OutBean.getOuts(OutBean.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

`NullPointerException` on `CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();`, Tried calling the `entitymanager` using `super.entitymanger` still the same error persists.

--
Thanks.

Comment: ```@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {

 @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "PRO")
 private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

 @Produces
 @Default
 @RequestScoped
 public EntityManager create() {
  return this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
 }

 public void dispose(@Disposes @Default EntityManager entityManager) {
  if (entityManager.isOpen()) {
   entityManager.close();
  }
 }
}```

Comment: @MitchBroadhead: Using container managed transaction!  the issue is, Using WebSphere 8.0.x, entity manager is available yet `getCriteriaBuilder` is not available at runtime. WebSphere uses openJPA!

Comment: error occurs exactly while resolving the following field 

openjpa.MetaData: Trace:  Resolving field "com.org.uck.pro.db.permission.entity.Permission@-1958444202.permissionName".
[2/8/18 9:52:52:043 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R   java.lang.NullPointerException
[2/8/18 9:52:52:043 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.populate(MetamodelImpl.java:321)

Comment: @MitchBroadhead  Have resolved the issue, the issues were related to Static metamodel code generated by hibernate JPA generator. Type mismatch because of a typo error in entity classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Inject annotation in BaseService

Should be like you have it done in OutRepositoryBean

```
@Inject @Pro
public EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: Any service called on base service works good , cos setting base service entity manager from ‘OutRepositoryBean’s ‘@Postconstruct init () ‘

Comment: Have resolved the issue, the issues were related to Static metamodel code generated with hibernate JPA generator. Type mismatch because of a typo error in entity classes